# How would you apply Parsec to generate code from a DSL?

Tags: dsl, parsec, haskell

I've read [Chapter 16 of Real World Haskell on Parsec](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/using-parsec.html) . The examples in this chapter show how to use Parsec to extract data structures out of strings.

I'm wondering how one would go about applying Parsec to create an imperative-style DSL, one that would take input written in a DSL and translate it into Haskell, SQL, or Ruby code that can be executed.

I'm sorry if this is a general question, but any leads or examples would be appreciated.

Comment: For a DSL inside haskell, check out [quasiquoters](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Quasiquotation).

Comment: Parsec would help only with parsing the text of a DSL. During parsing it is natural to produce an AST (abstract syntax tree) - but if you want help translating the AST you need to look at a different technology. In Haskell it is common to use a "traversal style" generics library like Uniplate or SYB to help write translators, but you can write them with direct recursion if your language is simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For help in parsing a minimal language, take a look at the `Expr` module.

The Write a Scheme tutorial also demonstrates going from parsing to evaluating a language, via Parsec: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Write_Yourself_a_Scheme_in_48_Hours